# Qt5 private headers detection with Cmake doesn't work correctly on Fedora?

Tags: cmake, qt5, fedora

The Qt5 CMake files define targets for each Qt component requested, e.g Qt5::Gui, Qt5::Multimedia and so on. When the private headers for the module are installed, an accompanying Qt5::FooPrivate is declared, to be used if you need to add a dependency / include path on the private headers.

Unfortunately, on Fedora, the Qt5::FooPrivate target is available even when the RPM containing the private headers (eg, qt5-qtbase-private-devel) has **not** been installed. This caused a build failure for a project I maintain, where I want to optionally build some additional features, if the private headers are available, without requiring users to always install them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Fedora packages the subdirectories where the private headers should reside, in its main devel packages (eg, qt5-qtbase-devel RPM). The Qt5 CMake Config.cmake files check that these directories exist, and assume this means the private headers are available.

Until either the Fedora packaging is adjusted, or the Qt5 Config.cmake files are, the work-around is to manually check for one of the private files existing. E.g via CMake's CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX helper function.